# Drawable displayed before tween animation

Tags: android, animation, drawable, android-animation

I have an activity (A) that launches another activity (B) after a calculation.  My problem is that when Activity B is launched, an arrow drawable that is supposed to move from left to right while incrementing in size (scaled from .33 to 1) is first displayed for a very short fraction of time before it starts the tween animation.  The end result is a bothering flicker of the full size drawable right before it starts animating.

Everything seems to point that the problem is related to the animation file (.xml) and not to the java class.  This can be observed when I delete the line `arrowImage.startAnimation(arrowExtent);` in the following code:

```
protected void arrowAnimation(Animation arrowExtent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowimage);
        arrowImage.startAnimation(arrowExtent);
        arrowExtent.setFillAfter(true);
```

I have tried the following:

1. Using setImageDrawable instead of setImageResource to the Drawable object.
2. Setting `arrowImage.setFillBefore(false);`

Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

The animation xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<set android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <scale
       android:fromXScale="0.33"
       android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:fromYScale="0.0"
       android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:startOffset="0"
       android:duration="1000"
       android:fillBefore="false" />

    <translate 
       android:fromXDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="75%p"
       android:duration="1000" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

When activity start you should make `ImageView` invisible in `xml` or in `onCreate()` and when animation starts, you should change it to visible.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // referencing views etc. 
    arrowImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    // or make image invisible in xml
}

protected void arrowAnimation(Animation arrowExtent) {
    arrowExtent.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            arrowImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { }
    });

    arrowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrowimage);
    arrowImage.startAnimation(arrowExtent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I forgot to mention that in order to be able to use a context menu in Activity B, I had to move the animation from `onCreate(`) to `onWindowsFocusChanged()`.  I tried the animation previously in `onCreate()` and obtained the same results.  The suggested code doesn't solve the problem, I noticed that when `arrowImage.startAnimation(arrowExtent)` is called the drawable whether visible or invisible, is drawn.

Comment: Also, tried the following to see if I observe some hint and I did.  I tried `arrowExtent.setStartOffset(1000)` in `arrowAnimation()`.  The result was: 1. Flicker of the arrowimage drawable. 2. One second of nothing. 3. The animation starting with arrowimage scaled and being transformed as the animation progresses.  So my gut feeling tells me that the animation xml file is drawing the arrowimage in the screen just before starting.  I am posting the animation xml.